# How to include an html encode php script in a layout template?

Tags: ee2, php, encode

Am trying to include an html encode php script on the very top of a layout template.

Am allowing php to execute on this layout template, however I end up with something like this

```
{!-- ra:000000007e39e89a000000001069d118 --}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not allowing PHP execution and using a plugin instead.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stringy
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun